# How to model non-Java dependencies not available in any repository using Maven?

Tags: java, maven

The Apache project log4cxx is implemented in C++, but uses Maven for historical reasons to manage web site and stuff. Some of the unit tests even require Java with e.g. `log4j` and at least that dependency is modeled in `pom.xml` like the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The good thing about this is that a [page containing that dependency](https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/latest_stable/dependencies.html) is automatically generated when building the web site. The bad thing about this approach is that it reads pretty much like those are ALL dependencies necessary at all, which is not the case. There are some additional ones to successfully build, like `APR`, and some shell tools like `sed` necessary to successfully run tests. It would be great to be able to maintain those dependency using the already available plugin as well.

For test purposes, I came up with the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>apr</groupId>
    <artifactId>util</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${user.home}/Documents/Svn/Src/Libs/trunk/C/X-OS/APR/apr-util/1.5.4/build/RAD 10.2/libs/libapr-util/Win32/Debug/out/libapr-util.lib</systemPath>
    <type>lib</type>
</dependency>
```

This adds an additional dependency to the page and let's the build succeed in the end, but still prints the following error message on the shell:

```
[ERROR] Artifact: apr:util:lib:1.5.4 has no file.
```

That is interesting, because using [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) I can see that the configured file is accessed and I don't see any other APR-named file requested at all.

```
13:57:58,5662686    java.exe    8312    CloseFile   C:\Users\tschoening\Documents\Svn\Src\Libs\trunk\C\X-OS\APR\apr-util\1.5.4\build\RAD 10.2\libs\libapr-util\Win32\Debug\out\libapr-util.lib  SUCCESS
```

Additionally, this only seems to work in case of using scope `system`, while I would like to model e.g. `sed` as being necessary for scope `test` instead. `system` is documented to be deprecated at all as well.

**So, is there some way to model additional dependencies in a way that Maven only uses them to create the corresponding page?** Would be great if one could tell Maven to not resolve some dependencies at all, but using `provided` or anything else than the above `system` didn't succeed.

Thanks!

Comment: `runtime` scope sounds more like what you're looking for

Comment: are `apr` and `util` identifiers that you invented? it seems the real thing uses different IDs: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.apr/apr-util/1.5.4 And contradictory to what you said, it is available in a repository, just not Maven Central.

Comment: Maven is quite Java-oriented when it comes to dependency management. Historically the way that dealing with binaries in Maven dependencies is to actually wrap them inside a jar file. You want to go a step further here, which probably involves creating your own [artifact handler](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/artifact-handlers.html). Unless you can find a third party plugin that already does something like this.

Comment: System scoped dependencies are indeed AVeryBadIdea(tm) and it is no wonder it is considered deprecated; just look at that beautiful hardcoded system-specific path you have set there just to be able to make it work. It is far more flexible and system-independent to create a local repository in the project itself and store the dependencies there. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762617/424903) demonstrates how to do that, but I don't think it will be able to help you create phantom dependencies like you seem to want to do.

Comment: For C++ there is a https://maven-nar.github.io/ (But that seemed to not maintained anymore)...

Answer (score 1):

To make things complete, the easiest approach really seems to be using a project-local Maven-repo to model dependencies. One simply needs to add some repo and the dependencies of interest to the `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <!-- Apache APR -->
    <repository>
        <id>mvn_tmatesoft_com</id>
        <name>maven.tmatesoft.com</name>
        <url>https://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Local repos to model non-public dependencies for different purposes. -->
    <repository>
        <id>log4cxx_non_public_deps</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/src/mvn_repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The important thing is that `${project.basedir}` supports any path where the project is placed at any deployment. Dependencies can be added as necessary:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.apr</groupId>
        <artifactId>apr</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.apr</groupId>
        <artifactId>apr-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4cxx.deps</groupId>
        <artifactId>gzip</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4cxx.deps</groupId>
        <artifactId>sed</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Because non-public dependencies are satisfied by the local repo, one is free on naming groups and stuff like that in theory. The last important step is to actually provide the dependencies in the correct directory as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
            xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4cxx.deps</groupId>
    <artifactId>gzip</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
    <packaging>zip</packaging>
</project>
```

> src/mvn_repo/org/apache/logging/log4cxx/deps/gzip/1.10.0/gzip-1.10.0.pom

All those dependencies are than used by the Maven-dependency plugin.

https://github.com/apache/logging-log4cxx/pull/35
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4cxx/pull/35/commits/2a5c157896b26c4c6445b1644de8266d3d0b54b1